# How do I open a file from Spotlight in Finder?

Tags: finder, spotlight

When I search for something e.g. a PDF file, in Spotlight and has i displayed in the search results list. How can I open the file in Finder? If I click on it, the file is opened e.g. in the pdf reader, but I would like to know where on the file system it is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>↩</kbd> does the trick.

Comment: Are you sure? This does not work for me.

Comment: works for me :-) Did you change key assignments in the past?

Comment: ⌘R and ⇧⌘R work as well.

Comment: Oh, wait. I thought that by return you meant the ``<-`` key. :-) I'm German and got confused. Now, it works for me as well.

Comment: Matt, the "Rücktaste" is definitively something different :-)

Comment: Is this a MacOS convention, or is it listed somewhere official?

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund I never seen it is listed somewhere official, but CMD and click does the same for Dock items. At least it did, don't know if it still does. This might be coincidental.